# How to use same strongly-typed editor view for both create and edit view models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to refactor an editor screen. The editor's model was the domain model, and I'm moving to a view model for this screen because I need to only allow edit of a couple of fields if the user has a certain role. I want to use the same editor view for both creating and editing the model, though that may be part of my problem.

I've read elsewhere on SO that view models should be simplistic, so there is no need for something like an interface hierarchy in view models. However, how can I use the same strongly-typed view for two different view models, one for create and one for edit, since the view models will have almost-the-same-but-slightly-different properties depending on the user role?

Here's a simplified example using the two view models I created:

```
public class RequirementCreateView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Justification { get; set; }
    public string ImpactIfNotFunded { get; set; }
    ... etc for about 40 properties ...
}

public class RequirementEditView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Justification { get; set; }
    public string ImpactIfNotFunded { get; set; }
    public string Decision { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    ... etc for about 40 properties ...
}
```

The two view models are identical except the Edit model has two extra properties *Decision* and *Status* that can only be set by someone with the appropriate role. I use AutoMapper to map from the domain Requirement object to the view model and vice-versa for the create/update action.

However, now that I have two view models obviously I can't use a single strongly-typed editor screen because things like ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Name) won't work. That led me to consider an interface hierarchy for this set of view models, like so:

```
IRequirementEditorView             -->  common properties
    |--> IRequirementCreateView    -->  create-specific properties (none right now)
    |--> IRequirementEditView      -->  edit-specific properties
```

And then have the editor view screen reference IRequirementEditorView. But again, that goes against the current wisdom on simplistic view models. But then the alternative is to duplicate my editor screen, which violates DRY.

This obviously is a common problem, but I'm stumped right now. Any advice?

Thanks.

**Edit** I should clarify after looking at some other SO similar posts: when I say I'm using the "same" editor view screen, I am using two separate views, Create.cshtml and Edit.cshtml. Each of these then simply references a partial view that contains the actual editor form like so:

```
@Html.Partial("Controls/RequirementEditor", Model, ViewData)
```

That is what I had in place when I was using the domain object as the view model.

Comment: Why do you feel it wrong to use a Partial representing the common properties of both the views?

Comment: I actually considered that yesterday but that prevents me from using expressions like in ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Name) because it requires a strongly-typed model. Which leads me back to the idea of the interface hierarchy for the view models. Doing that allows me to use the partials, but it goes against the advice I've always read to not over-complicate the view models. So I'm guessing there is another way of thinking about this that I'm not grokking yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was another way of thinking about this. Shortly after I posted this question I made a few changes and I'm much happier with the result. Here's what I did:

1. View model now has additional bool properties AllowDecisionEdit and AllowStatusEdit.
2. View model has two new IEnumerable properties DecisionsList and StatusList.
3. 1 and 2 are populated in the controller and passed to the appropriate view (create or edit).
4. The create view calls Html.BeginForm() then calls the partial Html.Partial("Controls/RequirementEditor/Editor"). The edit view does the same but also adds Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id) before the partial call to ensure the edit form works properly.

So now I have one edit model, one editor partial form, two separate views (create and edit) that each use the same partial and the same editor, and the functionality is turned on or off in the controller. My approaches above smelled very, very bad and I wasn't happy with either one. Once I did this everything felt right with the world. :)